# socket.getInetAddress() returns nothing

Tags: java, android, sockets, ip

I use the following code to get the IP from network where my server is running on an android Phone.
Earlier the same code was working fine. Now it does not returns an IP.

Note: I have not made any changes to this code.

Code:

```
  public String getIpAddress() {
            String ip = "";
            try {
                Enumeration<NetworkInterface> enumNetworkInterfaces = NetworkInterface
                        .getNetworkInterfaces();
                while (enumNetworkInterfaces.hasMoreElements()) {
                    NetworkInterface networkInterface = enumNetworkInterfaces
                            .nextElement();
                    Enumeration<InetAddress> enumInetAddress = networkInterface
                            .getInetAddresses();
                    while (enumInetAddress.hasMoreElements()) {
                        InetAddress inetAddress = enumInetAddress
                                .nextElement();

                        if (inetAddress.isSiteLocalAddress()) {
                            ip += "Server running at : "
                                    + inetAddress.getHostAddress();
                        }
                    }

                }

            } catch (SocketException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                ip += "Something Wrong! " + e.toString() + "\n";
            }
            return ip;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Has there been an android update?

Comment: No  updates. In the morning it was working fine, i went office and back when i started it started showing null IP.